# AD Domain Services using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Anyone had any luck deploying AD Domain Services?

**NOTE:** I've deployed the Classic vNet via ARM already prior to deploying ADDS

I've tried with the following JSON code, but I get this error:

**Error**

> "RequestConflict",
>
> "message": "Cannot replace resource with id
>   '' because the resource entity tag
>   has changed while processing this request. Please retry the request
>   with the updated resource."

**JSON Code**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "adds-settings": {
        "type": "object",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "These are settings for the AD Domain Services"
        }
    },
    "tag-values": {
        "type": "object",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "These are the Tag values"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.AAD/DomainServices",
        "name": "[parameters('adds-settings').domainName]",
        "apiVersion": "2017-01-01",
        "location": "[parameters('adds-settings').location]",
        "properties": {
            "domainName": "[parameters('adds-settings').domainName]",
            "vnetSiteID": "[parameters('adds-settings').vnetSiteID]",
            "subnetId": "[parameters('adds-settings').subnetId]"
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "addsID": {
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.AAD/DomainServices', parameters('adds-settings').domainName)]",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "dnsServers": {
        "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.AAD/DomainServices', parameters('adds-settings').domainName).domainControllerIpAddress]",
        "type": "array"
    }
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: is this the default template? did you alter it somehow?

Comment: Yeah it's the default template and I just feeding it parameters passed from a parent template.

Comment: Appears to be some sort of access issue. I'm using a Resource Group Deployment task in VSTS. If I kick off the deployment manually in the Portal , it's a different error. 'Error adding provisioning domain to service: Microsoft.DCaaS.Diagnostics.DisplayableException. The service principle with appid "xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" could not be found in the Azure Active Directory tenant '

Comment: @mrptsai We need to register Azure Active Directory Application service principal before creating the AADDS. Use below command to register the required service principal.
# New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -AppId "2565bd9d-da50-47d4-8b85-4c97f669dc36"

Answer (score 0):

You might be out of luck..

**Can I enable Azure AD Domain Services using a Resource Manager Template?**

No, it is not currently possible to enable Azure AD Domain Services using a template. Instead use PowerShell, see [how to enable Azure AD Domain Services using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-enable-using-powershell).

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-faqs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can...  Below is sample ARM resource I use:  Takes quite a while but it works...

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.AAD/domainServices",
  "name": "[parameters('Domain')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "domainName": "[parameters('Domain')]",
    "subnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('virtualNetworkName'), variables('subnetAD'))]",
    "ldapsSettings": {
      "ldaps": "Disabled",
      "externalAccess": "Disabled"
    },
    "domainSecuritySettings": {
      "ntlmV1": "Enabled",
      "tlsV1": "Enabled",
      "syncNtlmPasswords": "Enabled"
    },
    "filteredSync": "Disabled"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
  ]
},
```